# Extract variable from JSON result

Tags: json, dictionary, get, request, elevation

I am trying to extract the elevation variable from the JSON response of the OpenElevation API:

```
coordinates = stations.iloc[2]['Lat'] + ', ' + stations.iloc[2]['Long']
url = 'https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=' + coordinates
resp = rq.get(url)
print(resp.json())

OUTPUT: https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=51.52128377, -0.084605692
{'results': [{'latitude': 51.52128377, 'longitude': -0.084605692, 'elevation': 27}]}
```

How do I extract the 'elevation' variable so I can add it to my existing dataframe (stations) in a new column.

I have already tried this:

```
resp = rq.get(url)
resp_dict = json.loads(resp.json)
print(resp_dict['results']['elevation'])

OUTPUT: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not method
```

And when I try to use

```
print(resp.json['results']['elevation']())
OUTPUT: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

I feel like the solution is pretty simple but I have not been able to figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: `resp_dict['results'][0]['elevation']` or if you have more than one result, just iterate over `resp_dict['results']`. or use comprehension if you prefer - `[result['elevation'] for result in resp_dict['results']]`

Comment: But I can not seem to load my json file to a sting or dictionary.
When I use: `resp = rq.get(url)` -> `resp_dict = json.loads(resp)` I get a **TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response**
and `resp_dict = json.loads(resp.json)` I get the **the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Method**

Skipping json.loads or json.dumps all together also does not seem to work.

Comment: you should call `resp.json()` instead of `resp.json`. that method call will parse the response body to python dict. on the other hand `resp.content` will return bytes object, and you can pass it to `json.loads`. 
summarizing, you can call `resp.json()` or `json.loads(resp.content)` and they will give you same result.

Comment: When the solution is so simple you don't think of it.... Thanks!